# how to fetch string and add to a drop down list using java and Ms access at backend

Tags: java, sql, database, ms-access-2007

I'm having a problem related to a database project.
I need to show a JSP page having a drop down list of all the test names available in the database table, which is of the form
`Test_List(Test_ID, Test_Name, No_of_Que)`

I tried a few things :

```
<select name="test name">
     <%
        try{
           Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:Exam","","");
           Statement st = con.createStatement();
           String sql ="Select * from Test_List";
           ResultSet rs =st.executeQuery(sql);
      %>
<select name="test">
     <%
       while(rs.next()){
       String val=rs.getString("Test_Name");
     %>
   <option><%val%></option>
     <%
       }catch(SQLException e){out.print(e);}
     %>
</select>
```

here I tried to get value to be saved in string val and then searching for any option by which I can set this string to the option list of Dropdown menu...

Answer (score 0):

Try it as:
`
<%

```
               try{
               Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:Exam","","");
               Statement st = con.createStatement();
               String sql ="Select * from Test_List";
               ResultSet rs =st.executeQuery(sql);
               %><select name="test"><%
                String val=rs.getString("Test_Name");
                i++;
                %><%out.println("<option>"+val+"</option>");%><%

               }
        %>
    </select>
```

`